# WPF - Using a custom comparer when sorting by multiple columns

Tags: c#, wpf, vb.net, sorting, listview

I have a ListView (GridView) that I want to sort by 2 columns, so if 2+ items have the same value in Column 1, it sorts by Column 2. Pretty easy. But empty strings show up at the top when sorting A-Z. I'd like to move them to the bottom. I made a comparer (IComparer) that takes care of this, but I'm not sure how to use it.

Here's the code I tried:

```
 Dim view As ListCollectionView = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(myCollection)
 Using view.DeferRefresh
    view.SortDescriptions.Clear()
    view.SortDescriptions.Add(New SortDescription(sortHeader.Header, direction))
    view.SortDescriptions.Add(New SortDescription(otherColumn, direction))
    view.CustomSort = New MyComparer()
 End Using
```

The problem is my comparer is given a type of my class instead of the value of the property/column being sorted by. So if the class is Foo and I'm sorting by Foo.Bar, I get the entire Foo class, not just the value of Bar (which is really all it should be concerned about, since that's what it's sorting by).

How will my comparer know which property to compare? Maybe I'm doing something wrong here, because this doesn't make any sense. I expected to get a String (the property type) for x and y...

Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your `IComparer` implementation will be given the entire object, you need to figure out which column gets clicked, probably by doing something like this:

```
this.AddHandler(GridViewColumnHeader.ClickEvent, 
                new RoutedEventHandler(Column_Sort));
```

and then feed that into your `MyComparer` probably by modifying your constructor to take in the property path.

In `Column_Sort` you can get the property path something like this (I'm a little rusty on vb, but c# would do this:

```
void Column_Sort(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
  var memberBinding= ((GridViewColumnHeader)e.OriginalSource).Column.DisplayMemberBinding;
  var path = ((Binding)memberBinding).Path.Path;
}
```

and then feed that into your sorting logic.

```
Dim view As ListCollectionView = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(myCollection)
 Using view.DeferRefresh
    view.SortDescriptions.Clear()
    view.SortDescriptions.Add(New SortDescription(sortHeader.Header, direction))
    view.SortDescriptions.Add(New SortDescription(otherColumn, direction))
    view.CustomSort = New MyComparer(PropertyPath)
 End Using
```

**EDIT:**
You just need to customize your `IComparer` to support multiple column sorting, I googled and found [this comparer implementation](http://blog.iannelson.systems/universal-comparer-for-net/) that you can feed it several property paths separated by commas and suffixed with ASC/DESC like this:

```
User.LastName DESC, User.FirstName DESC
```

I think the convention for multi-column sorting as far as UI is concerned is that you need to have the `Ctrl` button held. So subclass the ListView class and tie into the GridViewColumnHeader clicked event and the KeyDown event to know which columns were clicked in succession and then use an `IComparer` implementation to feed that into.

Comment: This works when sorting by one column, but since the PropertyPath refers to the column that was clicked (which is also sortHeader in my code), it looks to that column even when it should be comparing the second column (the second SortDescription). How does the comparer know if it should look to the first column (the clicked one) or the second (when there's 2+ that have the same value in column 1)?

Comment: Made some changes above to try answer you exact question :)